# How do I use a Java Layout Manager to display the panels in the way i want?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I am currently trying to make a program using four panels. Three panels are grouped together on the left side of the JFrame using GridLayout and the last one takes up the right side of the screen. Ideally, the left panel will take up the 2/3 of the left side of the JFrame and the last third will be taken up by the fourth panel. I have attempted to do this in many ways and can't figure it out. The current display splits the screen in half and displays yellow, red, blue on top of each other, but only 540 pixels long, while the green is covering up the rest of the left panel.

This has the green rectangle representing the last panel and it is overlapping the yellow red and blue rectangles which should be 720 pixels long. I have accomplished properly displaying the way I want by re-sizing the JFrame until i made it work. By re-sizing till the rectangles line up i managed to make it look like it should. I moved the right side of the JFrame until the two respective panels lined up with no white space or overlap, unfortunately, in order to do this there is a ton of excess white space on the side.

Here is the code i used to make this display. I am a complete novice with swing and might have completely done this wrong. I am not set on using GridLayout, I just want to make this work correctly.

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class testJPanel1 extends JPanel        //topLeft
{
    int x,y;
    //JPanel Tjp1;
    public testJPanel1()
    {
        x=720;
        y=250;
        setSize(x,y);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("1",x,y);
        System.out.println("Hey 1 works");
    }
}
class testJPanel2 extends JPanel        //mid left
{
    int x,y;
    public testJPanel2()
    {
        x=720;
        y=260;
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(x,y);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("2",x,y);
        System.out.println("Hey 2 works");
    }
}
class testJPanel3 extends JPanel        //bot left
{
    int x,y;
    int boundsx;
    int boundsy;
    public testJPanel3()
    {
        x=720;
        y=250;
        boundsx=200;
        boundsy=200;
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(x,y);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("3",x,y);
        System.out.println("Hey 3 works");
       // g.drawRect(0,0,boundsx,boundsy);
    }
}   
class testJPanel4 extends JPanel        //BIG one on the right
{
    int x,y;
    int boundsx;
    int boundsy;
    public testJPanel4()
    {
        x=360;
        y=760;
        boundsx=200;
        boundsy=200;
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(x,y);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        //g.fillOval(x,y,50,50);

        g.fillRect(0,0,x,y);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("4",x,y);
        System.out.println("Hey 4 works");
        //g.drawRect(0,0,boundsx,boundsy);
    }
}
class Left_Panel extends JPanel     //Combines 1 and 2 and 3 
{
    testJPanel1 tjp1;
    testJPanel2 tjp2;
    testJPanel3 tjp3;
    public Left_Panel()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        tjp1= new testJPanel1();
        tjp2= new testJPanel2();
        tjp3= new testJPanel3();
        add(tjp1);
        add(tjp2);
        add(tjp3);

    }
}

class combo_Panel extends JPanel        //combines left and right panels together
{
    Left_Panel lp;
    testJPanel4 tjp4;
    //GOAL IS TO MAKE THIS PANEL lp is 720,760 pixels and tjp4 360,760...still doesnt work
    public combo_Panel()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));     //HOW TO make this work the way i want it or use something else i want
        lp= new Left_Panel();
        lp.setSize(720,760);
        tjp4= new testJPanel4();
        tjp4.setSize(360,760);

        add(lp);
        add(tjp4);
    }
}
class Paint_Window extends JFrame
{
    combo_Panel combo;
    Paint_Window(String title)
    {
        super(title);
                //setLayout( new BoxLayout(combo,2));
                combo = new combo_Panel();
        setBounds(new Rectangle(1080,760));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                add(combo);
                //add(tjp5);
               //tjp1.repaint();
    }
}
public class testJPanel
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            Paint_Window window = new Paint_Window("Make your choice");
    }
```

Comment: To start with, don't screw with the x/y values of a component, they already have a concept of position which is defined by the lay out manager

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, you could try laying out all three panels in a single container using a `GridLayout`, but that might not be possible, the other choice might be to use a `GridBagLayout` and adjust the `weightx` property to suit your requirements, for example...

[image: Layout]

Note the red "border" around the blue and green panels, this is showing the parent container for these two components

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel leftSide;
        private JPanel rightSide;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            leftSide = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            leftSide.setBackground(Color.RED);
            leftSide.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

            leftSide.add(createPanel(Color.BLUE));
            leftSide.add(createPanel(Color.GREEN));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 0.67;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(leftSide, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 0.33;
            rightSide = createPanel(Color.MAGENTA);
            add(rightSide, gbc);

        }

        protected JPanel createPanel(Color color) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(50, 100);
                }
            };
            panel.setBackground(color);
            return panel;
        }
    }

}
```